# Launching Chrome and debugging from within Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to debug some front-end javascript (for a Wordpress plugin). I am having trouble configuring the launch.json file correctly.

I can launch chrome manually and then attach to it after the fact (using an Attach request), in which case javascript breakpoints work fine fine.

If I launch chrome from within vscode (using the Launch request), it does connect (I see console output) but I don't get my breakpoints firing. I assume there is some setting incorrect in my launch.json file.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Signup Form",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://myclient.dev/signup-form",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "../../..",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ]
    },

    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222
    }
]
```

}

I've tried whatever I could think of for web root (including the full local path to the web root at 'htdocs' and the relative path you see above. It doesn't seem to care what I put in there, so maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

The local project folder is here:

`/home/me/code/vagrant-local/www/wordpress-myclient/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/cee-signup-form`

On the server, that maps to:

`http://myclient.dev/wp-content/plugins/cee-signup-form`

In the page 'signup-form' I include the javascript file in question, using its full url.

Obviously, I can manually go the url and then attach every time I want to debug, but having a one-click launch and debug would be far superior.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

Please follow below steps:

1. Check you have installed "VS Code - Debugger for Chrome" extention.
2. First Put this code in .vscode/launch.json :

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Node",
      "port": 9229,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "start"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/client/src"
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Full-stack",
      "configurations": ["Node", "Chrome"]
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Go to the Debug mode in VS Code and start with 'Full-stack'.
4. Start npm

Refer this : https://github.com/auchenberg/timey

Comment: Hi @LennartKloppenburg, Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited and formatted.

Comment: Hi Vijay, is this config still valid? I'm getting an error on vscode 1.16.1. Basically I have one JS file with some code and when I try debugging

Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, on Ubuntu 14.04, it worked after having added

```
"runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
```

I have however to start chrome in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a bug in VSCode, and it is fixed in the latest version (1.2.1). After updating, I had to do three things.

**Update the Chrome Extension**

In VSCode, hit CTRL+P to bring up the Command Palette, then:

```
Extensions: Show Outdated Extensions
```

At this point it will let you update them. Learn more here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/extension-gallery#_update-an-extension

**Edit the launch config**

They now require absolute paths for the web root. So, I had to change the `webRoot` property of the `launch.json` file to explicitly include the workspace root.

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/../../..",
```

**Close all copies of Chrome before debugging**

This is annoying. But it works.